# Multiple markers at this line, syntax error

Tags: underscore.js, aptana, aptana3

```
<script type="text/template" id="receipt_template">
    <tbody>
        <%
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        %>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><%=data[i].receipt_id%></td>
            <td align="center"><%=data[i].date%></td>
            <td align="center"><%=data[i].name%></td>
            <td align="center"><%=data[i].area%></td>
            <td align="center"><%=data[i].invoice_id%></td>
            <td align="center"><%=data[i].amount%></td>
        </tr>
        <%
        }
        %>
        </tbody>
</script>
```

[image]

I tried to use html templating from underscore js (http://underscorejs.org/#template)
it works fine. Also empty errors from netbeans ide. But aptana ide shows error as "Multiple markers at this line, syntax error".

Have I done something wrong?. How can I turn off this warning?

Comment: looks like its trying to validate html, and is flagging the php code. nothing to worry about - it looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nothing wrong. Underscore templates use special, customizable markers form embedding javascript code. Your IDE is unable to parse those, and thinking is all HTML spits those errors.